# Why doesn't `echo abc^H` just print `ab`?

Tags: shell, terminal, special-characters

As I recall, `^H` means <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. I generated it by pressing <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL+H</kbd>.

So the `^H` should remove the last character, as it is the same as <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and it should act just as if I pressed <kbd>Backspace</kbd> at this position.

Why the does the output of `echo abc^H` remain `abc` and not `ab`?

Comment: `^H` means "cursor left one".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<kbd>backspace</kbd> is only moving the cursor backward.

<kbd>backspace</kbd> (or <kbd>delete</kbd> or whatever character depending on the configuration) deletes the last printed character only when these conditions are met:

- it is typed on the keyboard, not a command output like `echo` in your example
- the terminal device is in cooked mode (the usual case)

If you want to erase the <kbd>c</kbd> in your example, you need to overwrite it by another character, for example:

```
echo "abc^H "
```

Comment: Btw even `echo "abc^H "` didn't work for me, however `echo -e "abc\b "` did. I can't figure out why `^H` doesn't work. ps. My shell is bash 4.1.5 .

Comment: @Rush: Make sure you enter `^H` by typing `Ctrl-V`, `Ctrl-H`

Comment: technically: if cooked mode (in the driver), or something that behaves _like_ cooked mode such as bash+readline.

Answer (score 0):

By typing ^V^H, you are inserting a Backspace code in the string, not issuing a Backspace command. ^H is not required to be a destructive backspace; some software uses it for overprinting.

Afterthought: The creator(s) of echo(1) reasoned that if you type ^V and a control code, you do so because you want another process, not echo(1), to parse the control code. In the case of Ctrl-H, echo(1) puts 0x08 in the output string and shows that with a caret and an H. If the string is redirected to something that PARSES 0x08 as a destructive backspace in its INPUT, you might get the desired result.

Comment: The accepted answer already says so.

Comment: echo(1) does none of these things; the terminal driver and/or shell does, then passes the _result_ (a byte with value 0x08) to echo(1) which just outputs it like any other character code. Similarly in bash, ksh, zsh you can use `$'\b'` which the _shell_ converts to an 0x08 and passes to the program or other command.

Answer (score -2):

`stty erase ^H` that should solve it.